# Problem installing MySQL on debian 9 with virtualmin and webmin

Tags: webmin

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin, I just updated PHP to version 7.4 and everything is fine but now I get the error.

This script cannot be installed, as this server does not meet the necessary requirements: phpMyAdmin requires a MySQL database

Capture indicating the error:
[image: Capture indicating the error]

But my MySQL server is installed, I even did a test db and everything fine

Test that the mysql server is installed:
[image: Test that the mysql server is installed]

Comment: I don't use Webmin so I have no idea how to fix that, but phpMyAdmin can be installed to any web server so you don't need to use the Webmin installer; you could uncompress phpMyAdmin to the web root or some subdirectory on your webserver. That would be a workaround of the problem rather than a solution, but maybe it could get you going.